# master/detail template with action menu - right way to show both

Tags: android, fragment, master-detail

Beginner here, targetting sdk v14 and v17 for my learning...no need for older support.

I am using the master/detail template and trying to get an action menu (for SEARCH) to show up both in phone and tablet view.  Actually I can get it to work, but I have to duplicate up my code in both ItemDetailActivity.java and ItemListActivity.java

These are the methods that I have to have in both for SEARCH to work:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {  
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {
public boolean onClose () {
```

I only want to search the "detail", not the "list".

So my question: is there a way to associate the action bar with only the list fragment?  That way I can keep the search functions in 1 file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer what I (think) I know as I don't want to leave this question open.

From tracing in the debugger, it looks to me like the phone activity and the tablet activity are separate and if you want to hook up an actionmenu, you have to hook it up to both separately.